# OPC UA server client on raspberry pi2

Tags: opc-ua

Can anyone help me on how to install OPCUA server and client on raspberry pi 2. It is better if anyone could help me with command line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "freeopcua" pure Python OPC-UA client and server library.
Project home page: http://freeopcua.github.io/

Installation is quite easy but not very fast.
In my case it was enough to do following installations steps:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev
pip install cryptography
pip install freeopcua
```

Some [examples](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua/tree/master/examples).
Example client and server code in short form can be found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/freeopcua/0.9.0)

Answer (score -1):

It will be hard to find OPC UA servers and/or clients which can be directly installed on a device.
Instead there are many SDKs using which a developer can develop OPC UA server and/or client on a platform.

These are some of the latest and greatest OPC UA products launched recently.
http://opcconnect.opcfoundation.org/2017/04/new-products-april-2017/

Detect and SDK which suits your requirement and write a OPC UA server or client for Raspberry pi.

I hope it answers your questions